# Website Down ::> Accidentally dropped visitor_log and visitor_log_info tables in Database Admin

Tags: database, zend-framework

Getting this error in the logs:

> 2015-04-13T06:22:52+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] Connection refused (trying to connect via tcp://mysqlv112:3306)  in /data/14/1/150/111/1313763/user/1407123/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 129

Can I just create the table in the Database Admin to resolve this issue? What fields are in the tables for visitor_log and visitor_log_info? Please help!

Is this what I add to the log_visitor table?
[image: database admin create table]

Comment: in table magento is save customer url ,customer visited url list

Comment: is this for the table visitor_log?

Comment: That error says MySQL is down. First start it back up.

Comment: How do I start up MySQL? Sorry I am a noob web developer

Comment: On the server commandline try either `service mysqld restart` or check the `/etc/init.d/` directory for a MySQL startup script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting thates that PDO can't connect to the MySQL server. Are you sure you've set the right credentials? You can find them in `app/etc/local.xml`

For the tables, the following query will create the `log_visitor` and `log_visitor_info` tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_visitor` (
  `visitor_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Visitor ID',
  `session_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Session ID',
  `first_visit_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'First Visit Time',
  `last_visit_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Last Visit Time',
  `last_url_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Last URL ID',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`visitor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Log Visitors Table' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log_visitor_info` (
  `visitor_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Visitor ID',
  `http_referer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'HTTP Referrer',
  `http_user_agent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'HTTP User-Agent',
  `http_accept_charset` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'HTTP Accept-Charset',
  `http_accept_language` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'HTTP Accept-Language',
  `server_addr` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Server Address',
  `remote_addr` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Remote Address',
  PRIMARY KEY (`visitor_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Log Visitor Info Table';
```

Comment: Awesome! Website is up and running again ~ Thank you very much!